# Unable to get the otWhiteboard_update Signal from Host to other participant

Tags: angular, opentok, vonage, whiteboard

I'm trying to use the opentok Whiteboard functionality.

Scenario: As a participant in the session, I cannot catch the otWhiteboard_update signal from the host who initiated the Whiteboard operation.

https://github.com/aullman/opentok-whiteboard/blob/master/demo.html

```
OT.checkSystemRequirements = function () {
            return true;
        };
        angular.module('demo', ['opentok', 'opentok-whiteboard'])
        .controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', 'OTSession', function ($scope, OTSession) {
            $scope.connected = false;
            OTSession.init('YOUR_API_KEY', 'YOUR_SESSION_ID', 'YOUR_TOKEN', function (err) {
                if (!err) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.connected = true;
                    });
                }
            });
        }]);
```

- Do I have to publish the OTSession?
- Do I have to connect the OTSession?
- Do the other participants in the session have to subscribe to the OT Session stream (which is not available now)?

Please help me with this implementation. I tried a lot, but nothing works; I'm clueless :(

Comment: So this whiteboard you are using here is using webRTC signaling to send updates. For signaling to work, you must have a webRTC session created. Both users must be connected to the session. Users do not have to be subscribing to each others streams for the signaling to work, they just have to be connected to a session to receive signals.